# DeviceIoControl Kernel to Usermode with HANDLE c++

Tags: c++, kmdf, deviceiocontrol

I have a driver on Windows 7 x64, which works fine, but I can't figure out how to push a handle from the driver to my usermode application.

Here is my kernel mode code:

```
HANDLE hTest= 0xD34D;
memcpy(IRP->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer, &hTest, sizeof(hTest));
```

Now the usermode part:

```
HANDLE hTest;
DeviceIoControl(hDevice, GETHANDLE, NULL, 0, &hTest, sizeof(hTest), &BytesIO, 0);
```

hTest is always differnt, but never correct. DeviceIoControl succeeds, hDevice is valid.

Can someone tell me what I am missing? :)

Comment: What kind of buffering scheme does `GETHANDLE` define, per [Defining I/O Control Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543023.aspx) and [Buffer Descriptions for I/O Control Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540663.aspx)?

Comment: Its METHOD_BUFFERED

Comment: After copying the `HANDLE` data into the `SystemBuffer`, are you setting `Parameters.DeviceIoControl.OutputBufferLength = sizeof(hTest)` to indicate how many bytes you actually copied into the buffer? This is explained in the documentation I linked to. Can you provide a [mcve] of your actual `GETHANDLE` handler?

Comment: Wow I'm such an Idiot, I forgot to set the outputbufferlength. Thanks dude :)